# Mapserver / QGis and DEM GeoTIFF different nodata values behaviour

Tags: raster, dem, geotiff-tiff, mapserver, nodata

I Have a problem with novalue datas in my DEM… This is the workflow I did:

1. my DEM datas are in multiple Arcgis ASCII grids… Each .asc files have a header containing "NODATA_value  -99999.00". I opened the in QGIS 3.0.3 and merged them in QGIS
2. I save my new layer in GeoTiff format, close QGIS and reopen my new GeoTIFF. All the "nodata" values have a value of -99999.
3. I process my nodata values with `gdal_translate -co TILED=YES -of GTiff -a_nodata "-99999" input.tif outputNaN.tif`
4. On QGIS the outputNaN.tif has a correct behaviour, nodata are "no data"
5. I created a Mapserver 7.0.7 map file:

```
MAP
  OUTPUTFORMAT
      NAME "GTiff"
      DRIVER GDAL/GTiff
      MIMETYPE "image/tiff"
      IMAGEMODE INT16
      EXTENSION "tif"
  END

  NAME "Modèle numérique de terrain"
    EXTENT  -6.0001389 39.9998611 10.0001389 52.0001389
    MAXSIZE 4096
    PROJECTION
        "init=epsg:2154"
  END

  WEB
    METADATA
        "wcs_label"           "WCS Server"
        "wcs_onlineresource"  "http://localhost/cgi-bin/mapserv?map=/tmp/testNaN.map&"
        "wcs_enable_request" "*"
            "wcs_fees"            "none"
            "wcs_accessconstraints"    "none"
            "wcs_keywordlist"          "wcs,dem"
            "wcs_metadatalink_type"    "TC211"
            "wcs_metadatalink_format"  "text/plain"
            "wcs_metadatalink_href"    "http://localhost"
            "wcs_address"              ""
            "wcs_city"                 "Paris"
            "wcs_stateorprovince"      "IDF"
            "wcs_postcode"             "75000"
            "wcs_country"              "France"
            "wcs_contactelectronicmailaddress" "admin@gnone.world"
            "wcs_contactperson"            "me"
            "wcs_contactorganization"      "unemployed"
            "wcs_contactposition"          "manager"
            "wcs_contactvoicetelephone"    ""
            "wcs_contactfacimiletelephone" ""
            "wms_title"           "WMS Server"
            "wms_onlineresource"  "http://localhost/cgi-bin/mapserv?map=/tmp/testNaN.map&"
            "wms_srs"             "EPSG:2154"
            "wms_enable_request"  "*"
            "wfs_title"          "WFS Server" 
            "wfs_onlineresource" "http://localhost/cgi-bin/mapserv?map=/tmp/testNaN.map&" ## Recommended
            "wfs_srs"            "EPSG:2154 EPSG:4326 EPSG:5698" ## Recommended
            "wfs_abstract"       "WFS Server" 
            "wfs_enable_request" "*"  
      END
    END

  LAYER
        NAME TESTNAN
          DATA "/tmp/outputNaN.tif"
        STATUS ON
        TYPE RASTER
        PROCESSING "SCALE=AUTO"
        PROJECTION
           "init=epsg:2154"
        END
    METADATA
      "wms_title"         "DEM 75m"
      "wcs_description" "Modèle numérique de terrain"
      "wcs_name" "DEM 75m"
      "wcs_label" "DEM (rés: 75m)"
      "wcs_srs" "EPSG:2154"
      "wcs_enable_request" "*"
      "wcs_bandcount" "1"
      "wcs_band_names" "Altitude"
      "Altitude_band_description" "Altitude en mètres"
    END
  END
END
```

6. But this layer has now -32768 value where a "nodata" must be found. I tried to play with `PROCESSING "NODATA=OFF"` or `PROCESSING "NODATA=-32768"`but without success.

I know how to set in the layer properties in QGIS a transparency of 100% where pixel=-32768 . But I'd prefer to find a better solution. How can achieve this?

Comment: What do you mean with "this layer has now -32768 value where a "nodata" must be found"? You seem to have configurered the tif as a WCS coverage, do you mean that the output of WCS GetCoverage in image/tiff format has that other nodata value?

Comment: Thanks for your comment: by -32768 I mean:
When I select my merged tif file and I click with the "info" icon on a zone where I know there is no data I get a "Sans données" in my result window I translated as "No data"
When I do the same thing on my layer from my mapserver map I get -32768, when I click in a zone with values I get a correct value.
And yes I defined a WCS coverage corresponding to the maximum extent (rectangle) of my DEM datas

Comment: And do you read the image into QGIS through WCS?

Comment: Yes, because in fact I need to share my DEM on a mapserver.
It seems that my tif file appears correct when directly opened in QGIS3 but not while served via MasServer 7.

Comment: If you want to know what really happens read your WCS service with direct GetCoverage requests with curl, save the result on disk and check with gdalinfo. But I believe that your issue is real. Perhaps you must write your own GDAL outputformat for image/tiff http://mapserver.org/mapfile/outputformat.html

Comment: Ok, you have GDAL outputformat already but GDAL driver does not have direct creation option for nodata http://www.gdal.org/frmt_gtiff.html. How about adding alpha?

Comment: also adding `"wcs_rangeset_nullvalue" "-99999"`in my WCS metadata makes another strange behaviour… No data values became 0 !
But alpha channel might be a solution but is it possible with 1 band float32 tiff?

Comment: If MapServer is using -32768 as nodata and writes that also correctly into the GeoTIFF metadata then it is technically right but I do not know if QGIS interprets the metadata. I am not sure is alpha works with float32 1 band tiff but have a try with gdal_translate.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which explains how our "Focused question / Best answer" model operates. Please [Edit] the question in response to requests for clarification. It's not fair to those who would answer to need to mine the comments for critical information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution with help from @user30184.

In the layer METADATA I added two metadatas: `"wcs_rangeset_nullvalue" "-99999"`wich alone does no do anything but -99999 is my geoTiff "nodata" real value (in the tiff metadata there is a tag nodata=-99999).
For working it needs also `"wcs_rangeset_name" "DEM 75m"` , without this no WCS are sent to the client.

This is my complete and correct map file:

```
MAP
  OUTPUTFORMAT
      NAME "GTiff"
      DRIVER GDAL/GTiff
      MIMETYPE "image/tiff"
      IMAGEMODE FLOAT32
      EXTENSION "tif"
    TRANSPARENT ON
  END

  NAME "Modèle numérique de terrain"
    EXTENT  -6.0001389 39.9998611 10.0001389 52.0001389
    MAXSIZE 4096
    PROJECTION
        "init=epsg:2154"
  END

  WEB
    METADATA
        "wcs_label"           "WCS Server"
        "wcs_onlineresource"  "http://localhost/cgi-bin/mapserv?map=/tmp/testNaN.map&"
        "wcs_enable_request" "*"
            "wcs_fees"            "none"
            "wcs_accessconstraints"    "none"
            "wcs_keywordlist"          "wcs,dem"
            "wcs_metadatalink_type"    "TC211"
            "wcs_metadatalink_format"  "text/plain"
            "wcs_metadatalink_href"    "http://localhost"
            "wcs_address"              ""
            "wcs_city"                 "Paris"
            "wcs_stateorprovince"      "IDF"
            "wcs_postcode"             "75000"
            "wcs_country"              "France"
            "wcs_contactelectronicmailaddress" "admin@gnone.world"
            "wcs_contactperson"            "me"
            "wcs_contactorganization"      "unemployed"
            "wcs_contactposition"          "manager"
            "wcs_contactvoicetelephone"    ""
            "wcs_contactfacimiletelephone" ""
            "wms_title"           "WMS Server"
            "wms_onlineresource"  "http://localhost/cgi-bin/mapserv?map=/tmp/testNaN.map&"
            "wms_srs"             "EPSG:2154"
            "wms_enable_request"  "*"
            "wfs_title"          "WFS Server" 
            "wfs_onlineresource" "http://localhost/cgi-bin/mapserv?map=/tmp/testNaN.map&" ## Recommended
            "wfs_srs"            "EPSG:2154 EPSG:4326 EPSG:5698" ## Recommended
            "wfs_abstract"       "WFS Server" 
            "wfs_enable_request" "*"  
      END
    END

  LAYER
        NAME TESTNAN
          DATA "/tmp/outputNaN.tif"
        STATUS ON
        TYPE RASTER
        PROCESSING "SCALE=AUTO"
        PROJECTION
           "init=epsg:2154"
        END
    METADATA
      "wms_title"         "DEM 75m"
      "wcs_description" "Modèle numérique de terrain"
      "wcs_name" "DEM 75m"
      "wcs_label" "DEM (rés: 75m)"
      "wcs_srs" "EPSG:2154"
      "wcs_enable_request" "*"
      "wcs_bandcount" "1"
      "wcs_band_names" "Altitude"
      "Altitude_band_description" "Altitude en mètres"
      "wcs_rangeset_nullvalue" "-99999"
      "wcs_rangeset_name" "DEM 75m"      
    END
  END
END
```